# Can't resolve '@splinetool/runtime' when try to deploy on GitHub pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm, spline

hi geeks I am trying to deploy my website through Github pages
so I saw this video that shows me how to deploy the Nextjs website to Github pages.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dalXCXCIPHM

but the build was failed with this error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@splinetool/react-spline/dist/react-spline.es.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@splinetool/runtime' in '/home/runner/work/abdallahzaher2022/abdallahzaher2022/node_modules/@splinetool/react-spline/dist'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@splinetool/react-spline/dist/react-spline.es.js
./components/WelcomeComp.tsx


> Build failed because of webpack errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abdallahzaher@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abdallahzaher@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-11-24T15_13_56_537Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

so I found that problem is with the spline 3d model
I hope there is a solution because the `npm run build` runs successfully

this is some of my changes that i think it is related

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    loader: "akamai",
    path: " ",
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next export"
  },
```

and finally this is the workflow file in nodejs config in github pages

```
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build 
    - run: npm run export

    - name: Deploy 
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
      with:
          folder: out # The folder the action should deploy.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already solved it, but here we go:

So, to debug this, the following information would be required:

- Is it deploying correctly on Vercel?
  The image 'akamai' loader is usually not required if you deploy on Vercel since they optimize much stuff behind the scenes.
- A complete package.json

**Suggestion**: Use the default Next.js workflow configuration provided by GitHub Pages and see if the error vanishes.

Finally, here's one of my [Next.js websites](https://github.com/Suvraneel/Suvraneel.github.io) where I've used Spline extensively.
Feel free to use [`components/SplineObj.js`](https://github.com/Suvraneel/Suvraneel.github.io/blob/main/components/SplineObj.js) as a template.